# PostgreSQL connection string

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to use PostgreSQL in a VS2017 window forms application.  I have succeeded in making the connection using an IP address (e.g. 192.168.0.14).  However, if I use the machine name, the connection is refused.  A ping returns an IPv6 address.  I am assuming that PostgreSQL can not use IPv6.  Is there a setting in the connection string that will allow PostgreSQL to use a IPv6 result?

Comment: Does that ipv6 belong to you? Does postgresql listen to that address?

Comment: please have a look at `.../data/pg_hba.conf` on the server. there you can set `host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5` for IPv6 connections